# Universal cloud storage client

Tags: windows, cloud-storage

I'm looking for universal cloud storage client (for windows at least).

For example google drive client, automatically sync files from directory to google drive.
Same with oneDrive client, and dropbox.

What I'm looking is client that is capable to do same thing but for multiple different cloud storages. So I have directory which if I put file in it it will be automatically uploaded to all configured storages.

I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options:

- [Rclone](https://rclone.org/) + Rclone Browser
  Rclone helps you:

> Backup (and encrypt) files to cloud storage
> Restore (and decrypt) files from cloud storage
> Mirror cloud data to other cloud services or locally
> Migrate data to the cloud, or between cloud storage vendors
> Mount multiple, encrypted, cached or diverse cloud storage as a disk
> Analyse and account for data held on cloud storage using lsf, ljson, size, ncdu
> Union file systems together to present multiple local and/or cloud file systems as one

- [CloudCross](https://github.com/MasterSoft24/cloudcross): seems to be abandoned since 2020